# Wordpress basic concept - how to extend/override/customize a plugin hook?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hook

I am working on a wordpress site and would like to clarify a basic concept that is definitely very important, and this is **how to customize/extend a wordpress hook** (at least that's what I think I want to do!)

As the real world example, I am setting up a wp-ecommerce site. When a user adds an item to the cart, I would like to do one or two more things than the original function does. Looking through the source, I find:

```
/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-includes/ajax.functions.php
```

with the function:

```
function wpsc_add_to_cart()
```

I know I could simply edit the code right here, but obviously that is the completely wrong way to go about it as when the plugin is updated, I will lose changes. What is the correct way to extend a function that is part of a plugin, or wordpress for that matter?

Endless thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wordpress action hooks to resolve the code loss while plugin upgrade.

You can remove the function which is in plugin file by using remove_action hook and do your own code by adding add_action in your function.php file. So that you can customize your plugin code from theme's function.php.

Here are the examples to explain.I hope it will help.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

http://themeshaper.com/2009/05/03/filters-wordpress-child-themes/

Answer (score 2):

I use a little supressed notice function (it lives in my child themes function.php page), for plugins that get irritating eg: please setup twitter account to use , this kind of warning is not useful at certain stages and sometimes just do not care for it.

```
function supressed_notices_active(){
    echo '<div class="error"><p>Supressed Notices are active</p></div>';
}
if(function_exists('the_plugin_custom_function_call')){
    remove_action('the_plugin_custom_function_call' );
    add_action('admin_notices','supressed_notices_active');
}else{
    function test_message_from_me(){
        echo '<h1>show</h1>';
    }
    add_action('admin_notices','test_message_from_me');
}
```

So I create the supressed notice function to at least create a warning, so i remember.

Check if the target function exists with the `function_exists($target_function)` hook

then remove this action from running with the `remove_action($tag,$target_function)` hook

then just add your custom function with the `add_action($tag,$target_function)` hook (do not need to have a separate function this could just be a closure)

then else if the function does not exist either still run a new action or leave this section, it can be useful for testing to just add anything so you atleast get some feed back.

Answer (score -1):

What you could try... Copy the function within the plugin file, 
paste it into your themes functions.php file,

ie:

```
function wpsc_add_to_cart() {
    global $wpdb, $wpsc_cart;
    // default values etc..etc..

    // new code here?
}
```

the only thing with this is, if the plugin is updated and that funciton is renamed or removed, changed or something you could start to run into trouble...

could you not ask the plugin developer to possibly add your requirements to it, 
possibly for a small fee? but if your using it as your main shopping cart, then chances are, that small investment could be a good thing.

Marty

Comment: You won't be able to redeclare PHP function, you will get an error saying it has been previously declared within the plugin.